# TL-WN821N Wifi not working correctly

Tags: wireless, networking

I have a TL-WN821N wifi USB device which worked fine (gave me a connection) when I was installing Ubuntu on my PC. It downloaded all the updates and what not and got the OS installed.

I even opened terminal after installation to see if I have a working connection by using ping command. And I did.

Now when I open up Firefox and go to a webpage, it will load the webpage and after that the connection is gone,  it still show like I am connected to the internet in the WIFI status indicator but no futher pages can be opened and the ping command does not work anymore too.

What might be the case here?

I want to say that I have now used to help from the web. Used ndisgtk and added some files to /etc/modprobe

My Ubuntu installation now does not even see that I have this USB device connected to my computer. I reverted all changes and it still will not even see the device. I used lusb or whatever the command was  ans lshw also to see it. Nothing showed up.

So what can I do now at this point? How can I make my computer atleast detect the device.

Info with the wifi script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy

##### kernel #####

Linux kaspar-All-Series 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8554]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:000d Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c326 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0781:5406 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro U3
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0)

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #####

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

##### iwlist channel #####

##### lsmod #####

##### modinfo #####

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf]
blacklist nouveau
blacklist nvidia
blacklist nvidia-current
blacklist nvidia-current-updates
blacklist nvidia-304
blacklist nvidia-304-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-304
blacklist nvidia-310
blacklist nvidia-310-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-310
blacklist nvidia-313
blacklist nvidia-313-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-313
blacklist nvidia-319
blacklist nvidia-319-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-319
blacklist nvidia-325
blacklist nvidia-325-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-325
blacklist nvidia-331
blacklist nvidia-331-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-331

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

########## wireless info END ############


May 20 13:01:59 kaspar-All-Series anacron[847]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
May 20 13:02:00 kaspar-All-Series dbus[618]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
May 20 13:02:00 kaspar-All-Series dbus[618]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.ScreenResolution.Mechanism'
May 20 13:04:27 kaspar-All-Series dbus[618]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' (using servicehelper)
May 20 13:04:27 kaspar-All-Series dbus[618]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
May 20 13:04:42 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
May 20 13:04:42 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/653acc3280a44adbbb0fb39b503c017c
May 20 13:04:42 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/653acc3280a44adbbb0fb39b503c017c
May 20 13:04:42 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/653acc3280a44adbbb0fb39b503c017c
May 20 13:04:43 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Updating cache
May 20 13:05:02 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/653acc3280a44adbbb0fb39b503c017c
May 20 13:05:32 kaspar-All-Series anacron[847]: Job `cron.weekly' started
May 20 13:05:32 kaspar-All-Series anacron[3813]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2014-05-20
May 20 13:05:45 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon: INFO: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('account-plugin-aim'), dbus.String('account-plugin-jabber'), dbus.String('account-plugin-salut'), dbus.String('account-plugin-yahoo'), dbus.String('app-install-data'), dbus.String('bash'), dbus.String('cups-browsed'), dbus.String('cups-filters'), dbus.String('cups-filters-core-drivers'), dbus.String('dpkg'), dbus.String('empathy'), dbus.String('empathy-common'), dbus.String('firefox'), dbus.String('firefox-locale-en'), dbus.String('firefox-locale-et'), dbus.String('flashplugin-installer'), dbus.String('gdb'), dbus.String('gettext'), dbus.String('gettext-base'), dbus.String('ghostscript'), dbus.String('ghostscript-x'), dbus.String('gir1.2-freedesktop'), dbus.String('gir1.2-glib-2.0'), dbus.String('gir1.2-gudev-1.0'), dbus.String('gir1.2-rb-3.0'), dbus.String('gnome-calculator'), dbus.String('gnome-control-center-shared-data'), dbus.String('icedtea-7-jre-jamvm'), dbus.String('ifupdown'), dbus.String('initramfs-tools'), dbus.String('initramfs-tools-bin'), dbus.String('iputils-arping'), dbus.String('iputils-ping'), dbus.String('iputils-tracepath'), dbus.String('libasprintf-dev'), dbus.String('libasprintf0c2'), dbus.String('libavcodec54'), dbus.String('libavformat54'), dbus.String('libavutil52'), dbus.String('libcupsfilters1'), dbus.String('libdpkg-perl'), dbus.String('libdrm-intel1'), dbus.String('libdrm-intel1:i386'), dbus.String('libdrm-nouveau2'), dbus.String('libdrm-nouveau2:i386'), dbus.String('libdrm-radeon1'), dbus.String('libdrm-radeon1:i386'), dbus.String('libdrm2'), dbus.String('libdrm2:i386'), dbus.String('libegl1-mesa'), dbus.String('libegl1-mesa-drivers'), dbus.String('libelf1'), dbus.String('libelf1:i386'), dbus.String('libfontembed1'), dbus.String('libfreetype6'), dbus.String('libfreetype6:i386'), dbus.String('libgail-common'), dbus.String('libgail18'), dbus.String('libgbm1'), dbus.String('libgettextpo-dev'), dbus.String('libgettextpo0'), dbus.String('libgexiv2-2'), dbus.String('libgirepository-1.0-1'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-dri'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-dri:i386'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-glx'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-glx:i386'), dbus.String('libglamor0'), dbus.String('libglapi-mesa'), dbus.String('libglapi-mesa:i386'), dbus.String('libgles2-mesa'), dbus.String('libgnome-control-center1'), dbus.String('libgs9'), dbus.String('libgs9-common'), dbus.String('libgtk2.0-0'), dbus.String('libgtk2.0-bin'), dbus.String('libgtk2.0-common'), dbus.String('libgudev-1.0-0'), dbus.String('libido3-0.1-0'), dbus.String('libjbig0'), dbus.String('libjbig0:i386'), dbus.String('liblightdm-gobject-1-0'), dbus.String('libmysqlclient18:i386'), dbus.String('libopenvg1-mesa'), dbus.String('libpam-systemd'), dbus.String('librhythmbox-core8'), dbus.String('libsdl1.2debian'), dbus.String('libselinux1'), dbus.String('libselinux1:i386'), dbus.String('libsmbclient'), dbus.String('libssl1.0.0'), dbus.String('libssl1.0.0:i386'), dbus.String('libswscale2'), dbus.String('libsystemd-daemon0'), dbus.String('libsystemd-journal0'), dbus.String('libsystemd-login0'), dbus.String('libtiff5'), dbus.String('libtiff5:i386'), dbus.String('libudev1'), dbus.String('libudev1:i386'), dbus.String('libunity-core-6.0-9'), dbus.String('libvlc5'), dbus.String('libvlccore7'), dbus.String('libwayland-egl1-mesa'), dbus.String('libwbclient0'), dbus.String('libxatracker2'), dbus.String('libxfont1'), dbus.String('libxml2'), dbus.String('libxml2:i386'), dbus.String('lightdm'), dbus.String('linux-firmware'), dbus.String('linux-generic'), dbus.String('linux-headers-3.13.0-24'), dbus.String('linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'), dbus.String('linux-headers-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-generic'), dbus.String('linux-libc-dev'), dbus.String('ltrace'), dbus.String('mcp-account-manager-uoa'), dbus.String('mysql-common'), dbus.String('nautilus-sendto-empathy'), dbus.String('nvidia-337'), dbus.String('nvidia-settings'), dbus.String('openjdk-7-jre'), dbus.String('openjdk-7-jre-headless'), dbus.String('openssl'), dbus.String('patch'), dbus.String('python-cupshelpers'), dbus.String('python-libxml2'), dbus.String('python-samba'), dbus.String('python3-software-properties'), dbus.String('python3-update-manager'), dbus.String('rhythmbox'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-data'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-mozilla'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugins'), dbus.String('rsync'), dbus.String('samba-common'), dbus.String('samba-common-bin'), dbus.String('samba-libs'), dbus.String('smbclient'), dbus.String('software-center'), dbus.String('software-properties-common'), dbus.String('software-properties-gtk'), dbus.String('steam-launcher'), dbus.String('system-config-printer-common'), dbus.String('system-config-printer-gnome'), dbus.String('system-config-printer-udev'), dbus.String('systemd-services'), dbus.String('thunderbird'), dbus.String('thunderbird-gnome-support'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-en'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-en-gb'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-en-us'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-et'), dbus.String('tzdata'), dbus.String('tzdata-java'), dbus.String('udev'), dbus.String('unity'), dbus.String('unity-greeter'), dbus.String('unity-services'), dbus.String('update-manager'), dbus.String('update-manager-core'), dbus.String('vlc'), dbus.String('vlc-data'), dbus.String('vlc-nox'), dbus.String('vlc-plugin-notify'), dbus.String('vlc-plugin-pulse'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-ati'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-intel'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-nouveau'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-radeon')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
May 20 13:05:45 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/cc1925d70e1446e787796b1de148b4f5
May 20 13:05:45 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/cc1925d70e1446e787796b1de148b4f5
May 20 13:05:45 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Committing packages: dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('account-plugin-aim'), dbus.String('account-plugin-jabber'), dbus.String('account-plugin-salut'), dbus.String('account-plugin-yahoo'), dbus.String('app-install-data'), dbus.String('bash'), dbus.String('cups-browsed'), dbus.String('cups-filters'), dbus.String('cups-filters-core-drivers'), dbus.String('dpkg'), dbus.String('empathy'), dbus.String('empathy-common'), dbus.String('firefox'), dbus.String('firefox-locale-en'), dbus.String('firefox-locale-et'), dbus.String('flashplugin-installer'), dbus.String('gdb'), dbus.String('gettext'), dbus.String('gettext-base'), dbus.String('ghostscript'), dbus.String('ghostscript-x'), dbus.String('gir1.2-freedesktop'), dbus.String('gir1.2-glib-2.0'), dbus.String('gir1.2-gudev-1.0'), dbus.String('gir1.2-rb-3.0'), dbus.String('gnome-calculator'), dbus.String('gnome-control-center-shared-data'), dbus.String('icedtea-7-jre-jamvm'), dbus.String('ifupdown'), dbus.String('initramfs-tools'), dbus.String('initramfs-tools-bin'), dbus.String('iputils-arping'), dbus.String('iputils-ping'), dbus.String('iputils-tracepath'), dbus.String('libasprintf-dev'), dbus.String('libasprintf0c2'), dbus.String('libavcodec54'), dbus.String('libavformat54'), dbus.String('libavutil52'), dbus.String('libcupsfilters1'), dbus.String('libdpkg-perl'), dbus.String('libdrm-intel1'), dbus.String('libdrm-intel1:i386'), dbus.String('libdrm-nouveau2'), dbus.String('libdrm-nouveau2:i386'), dbus.String('libdrm-radeon1'), dbus.String('libdrm-radeon1:i386'), dbus.String('libdrm2'), dbus.String('libdrm2:i386'), dbus.String('libegl1-mesa'), dbus.String('libegl1-mesa-drivers'), dbus.String('libelf1'), dbus.String('libelf1:i386'), dbus.String('libfontembed1'), dbus.String('libfreetype6'), dbus.String('libfreetype6:i386'), dbus.String('libgail-common'), dbus.String('libgail18'), dbus.String('libgbm1'), dbus.String('libgettextpo-dev'), dbus.String('libgettextpo0'), dbus.String('libgexiv2-2'), dbus.String('libgirepository-1.0-1'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-dri'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-dri:i386'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-glx'), dbus.String('libgl1-mesa-glx:i386'), dbus.String('libglamor0'), dbus.String('libglapi-mesa'), dbus.String('libglapi-mesa:i386'), dbus.String('libgles2-mesa'), dbus.String('libgnome-control-center1'), dbus.String('libgs9'), dbus.String('libgs9-common'), dbus.String('libgtk2.0-0'), dbus.String('libgtk2.0-bin'), dbus.String('libgtk2.0-common'), dbus.String('libgudev-1.0-0'), dbus.String('libido3-0.1-0'), dbus.String('libjbig0'), dbus.String('libjbig0:i386'), dbus.String('liblightdm-gobject-1-0'), dbus.String('libmysqlclient18:i386'), dbus.String('libopenvg1-mesa'), dbus.String('libpam-systemd'), dbus.String('librhythmbox-core8'), dbus.String('libsdl1.2debian'), dbus.String('libselinux1'), dbus.String('libselinux1:i386'), dbus.String('libsmbclient'), dbus.String('libssl1.0.0'), dbus.String('libssl1.0.0:i386'), dbus.String('libswscale2'), dbus.String('libsystemd-daemon0'), dbus.String('libsystemd-journal0'), dbus.String('libsystemd-login0'), dbus.String('libtiff5'), dbus.String('libtiff5:i386'), dbus.String('libudev1'), dbus.String('libudev1:i386'), dbus.String('libunity-core-6.0-9'), dbus.String('libvlc5'), dbus.String('libvlccore7'), dbus.String('libwayland-egl1-mesa'), dbus.String('libwbclient0'), dbus.String('libxatracker2'), dbus.String('libxfont1'), dbus.String('libxml2'), dbus.String('libxml2:i386'), dbus.String('lightdm'), dbus.String('linux-firmware'), dbus.String('linux-generic'), dbus.String('linux-headers-3.13.0-24'), dbus.String('linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'), dbus.String('linux-headers-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic'), dbus.String('linux-image-generic'), dbus.String('linux-libc-dev'), dbus.String('ltrace'), dbus.String('mcp-account-manager-uoa'), dbus.String('mysql-common'), dbus.String('nautilus-sendto-empathy'), dbus.String('nvidia-337'), dbus.String('nvidia-settings'), dbus.String('openjdk-7-jre'), dbus.String('openjdk-7-jre-headless'), dbus.String('openssl'), dbus.String('patch'), dbus.String('python-cupshelpers'), dbus.String('python-libxml2'), dbus.String('python-samba'), dbus.String('python3-software-properties'), dbus.String('python3-update-manager'), dbus.String('rhythmbox'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-data'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-mozilla'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist'), dbus.String('rhythmbox-plugins'), dbus.String('rsync'), dbus.String('samba-common'), dbus.String('samba-common-bin'), dbus.String('samba-libs'), dbus.String('smbclient'), dbus.String('software-center'), dbus.String('software-properties-common'), dbus.String('software-properties-gtk'), dbus.String('steam-launcher'), dbus.String('system-config-printer-common'), dbus.String('system-config-printer-gnome'), dbus.String('system-config-printer-udev'), dbus.String('systemd-services'), dbus.String('thunderbird'), dbus.String('thunderbird-gnome-support'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-en'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-en-gb'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-en-us'), dbus.String('thunderbird-locale-et'), dbus.String('tzdata'), dbus.String('tzdata-java'), dbus.String('udev'), dbus.String('unity'), dbus.String('unity-greeter'), dbus.String('unity-services'), dbus.String('update-manager'), dbus.String('update-manager-core'), dbus.String('vlc'), dbus.String('vlc-data'), dbus.String('vlc-nox'), dbus.String('vlc-plugin-notify'), dbus.String('vlc-plugin-pulse'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-ati'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-intel'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-nouveau'), dbus.String('xserver-xorg-video-radeon')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
May 20 13:05:46 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/cc1925d70e1446e787796b1de148b4f5
May 20 13:06:17 kaspar-All-Series anacron[847]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
May 20 13:06:41 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Cancelling transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/cc1925d70e1446e787796b1de148b4f5
May 20 13:06:42 kaspar-All-Series AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/cc1925d70e1446e787796b1de148b4f5
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'none') [100 20 0]
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1172
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[733]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe1c:a4a8 on wlan0.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[733]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe1c:a4a8.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[733]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.260807] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca by local choice (reason=3)
May 20 13:06:50 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1051]: message repeated 7 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1051]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca reason=3 locally_generated=1
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[733]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.103 on wlan0.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[733]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.103.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series dnsmasq[1490]: setting upstream servers from DBus
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.274986] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[733]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1041]: offline
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280262] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280266] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280268] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280270] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280272] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280273] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  691.280275] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series dbus[618]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series dbus[618]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set disabled
May 20 13:06:51 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
May 20 13:06:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
May 20 13:06:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
May 20 13:06:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
May 20 13:06:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
May 20 13:06:52 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  692.773533] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
May 20 13:06:52 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  692.784108] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  693.140284] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0) supports 4 scan SSIDs
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1051]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> (wlan0) supports 4 scan SSIDs
May 20 13:06:53 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[932]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Seened'.
```

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but I would try using another browser just to test what happens, that way you could know if it's being caused by firefox or something else. Also, did you test it with a Ethernet connection? Does it behave the same?

Comment: I am not sure my self also. But I followed a lot of info and one guy told to install ndisgtk, and install the windows driver for this card. I did it and now the Wifi connection will not show up at all. I reverted everything and it still does not...

Comment: Is there any kind of info I can give on this?

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer here so we may have the information to help you.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I added the info to my original post!

Comment: I am unable to find any trace of my Wifi USB device in that text. Also when my computer is running and the USB Wifi device is connected, it is not glowing anymore. It had green led glowing in it before.

Comment: Would still love some help on this. I am willing to provide any kind on info about the system. Also, I upgraded my self to 14.04 LTS, but it still did not fix the problem.

Comment: I added my syslog info to the end of the code page. One intresting line there is that the network gets a shutdown notice with reason (0 none).

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest mainline kernel. I found two bug reports: [ath9k_usb: TL-WN821N v3 Connection drops](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049383) and [compat-wireless disconnects randomly and locks system scheduler preventing process launch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42661). Also [overheating TL-WN821N v3](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61111). Do you see any errors in `dmesg`? Also try a different AP if you can, and try Open/WEP/WPA, it is possible there is some incompatibility with your existing AP/configuration.

Comment: My wifi stick is v4.1 tough

Comment: And it is using the RTL8192CU driver by default

Comment: I tried using this driver: https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes   but after I installed it, WIFI did not even show up anymore. As if I had no wifi device connected at all. But the driver should work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. So here is the official fix for TL-WN821N USB WIFI stick that uses the rtl8192cu driver:

**Installation**

Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

Clone this repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install it:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

There is a known issue with power management on some hardware. If your WiFi connection drops after a few minutes, install the following module setting file to disable power management in your WiFi interface:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/8192cu-disable-power-management.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

And reboot. You're done.

Info taken from this site: [rtl8192cu-fixed](http://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes)

Comment: Step 4: sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10

Comment: @Peterling updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with ubuntu 14.04 and resolved with thid solution , I'd like to update to 16.04 release, in this release this problem is resolved or can I resolve with this solution, thanks